# Why is this custom listener null?

Tags: android, listener, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create an interface between my Recyclerview Adapter and an Activity, so that when an item in the adapter is clicked, the Activity will react accordingly but the listener is always null.

**Interface**

```
public interface UrlTagCatClickedListener {
    public void onUrlTagCatClicked (String chemicalURL);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class TagCatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<TagCatItem> mTagCatItems;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    private UrlTagCatClickedListener mTagCatClickedListener;

    public  TagCatAdapter(List<TagCatItem> tagCatItems, Context context) {
        super();
        this.mTagCatItems = tagCatItems;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mTagCatClickedListener = null;
    }

    public void setTagCatClickedListener (UrlTagCatClickedListener tagCatClickedListener) {
        this.mTagCatClickedListener = tagCatClickedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.tag_cat_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  TagCatItem tagCatItem = mTagCatItems.get(position);
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).chemicalTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(tagCatItem.getChemicalTitle()));
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).chemicalDate.setText(tagCatItem.getChemicalDate());
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).chemicalTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTagCatClickedListener != null) { // mTagCatClickedListener is always null
                    mTagCatClickedListener.onUrlTagCatClicked(tagCatItem.getChemicalURL());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public  class  ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView chemicalTitle, chemicalDate;
        public  ItemViewHolder(final View mView) {
            super(mView);
            chemicalTitle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tagcat_title);
            chemicalDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tagcat_date);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTagCatItems.size();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called")
        //Skipped a lot of codes that doesn't relate to the queation

        List<TagCatItem> mTagCatItems = new ArrayList<>();

        TagCatAdapter tagCatAdapter = new TagCatAdapter(mTagCatItems, this);
        tagCatAdapter.setTagCatClickedListener(new UrlTagCatClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUrlTagCatClicked(String chemicalURL) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I go the url!!!!!!!!!! and it is + " + chemicalURL);
            }
        });
    }
```

Please, do you have an idea why it's null and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you creating and setting another `TagCatAdapter` instance anywhere in your code?

Comment: @MikeM. yes, in the fragment that contains the RecyclerView.

Comment: Well, then the one in your posted code is probably not the `Adapter` you're setting on the `RecyclerView`, so the one you set in the `Fragment` doesn't have that listener. Also, if the `RecyclerView`'s in a `Fragment`, you don't really wanna create the `Adapter` for it the `Activity` anyway.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is, you may be creating a another instance of `TagCarAdapter` and setting it to recycler. And its just a guess.

Comment: @MikeM. please can you expatiate your explanation?

Comment: @sha please what solution do you propose?

Comment: Get rid of the `TagCatAdapter` stuff in the `Activity`. Set your `UrlTagCatClickedListener` on the `TagCatAdapter` you create in the `Fragment` that contains the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @Ozuf Can you please post code where you are setting adapter to the recycler which will give more insight of whats happening?

Comment: @MikeM. Your suggestion fixed it. Thanks. Can you give it as an answer to the question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different instances of `TagCatAdapter` in your given setup; one in the `Activity`, and one in the `Fragment`. You're setting the `UrlTagCatClickedListener` you've posted on the one created in the `Activity`, but it's the `Fragment`'s `TagCatAdapter` instance that you're setting on the `RecyclerView`. That one doesn't have the listener set, so its `mTagCatClickedListener` is always null.

You just need to move the given `UrlTagCatClickedListener` to the `TagCatAdapter` in the `Fragment`, and remove the `TagCatAdapter` from the `Activity`, as you're not using that one anyway.